# Superset: Not able to show more info in the chart

Tags: javascript, apache-superset

I'm using a superset and using the library deck.gl.scatterplot to represent the data but in the chart I want to show more info about the points[image: Map]

So I got to know about the javascript tooltip generator where I'm using this code

`d => "<div>field: <strong> ${d.object.props.City}</strong></div>"`

to represent the city but I'm not able to use the city name. I've also added extra data for JS which it ask for just before this but still

how do i fix this? also I'm trying to find some documentation on it which can help me understand this better

Comment: If you want to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you should use backticks `\`` instead of quotes `"`

Comment: I tried this but then it doesn't show anything

Comment: also when I use backticks suddenly I'm not able to do anything. Can't even zoom